# Silence /dev/tcp/host/port redirection errors

Tags: bash

The following script will test if tcp port from 8079 to 8081 is open or closed.

```
for port in {8079..8081}; do
  echo >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/$port &&
    echo "port $port is open" ||
    echo "port $port is closed"
done
```

Output

```
user@linux:~$ ./script.sh 
./script.sh: connect: Connection refused
./script.sh: line 2: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8079: Connection refused
port 8079 is closed
port 8080 is open
./script.sh: connect: Connection refused
./script.sh: line 2: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8081: Connection refused
port 8081 is closed
user@linux:~$
```

How do I remove the following lines? I've tried to redirect stderr to `/dev/null` like `2>/dev/null` but didn't work.

```
./script.sh: connect: Connection refused
./script.sh: line 2: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8079: Connection refused
```

Desired Output

```
user@linux:~$ ./script.sh 
port 8079 is closed
port 8080 is open
port 8081 is closed
user@linux:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried to redirect stderr to /dev/null like 2>/dev/null but didn't work.

Actually it works. It's just you need to redirect the whole loop's stderr<sup>*</sup>, not just `echo`'s; as it's not `echo` that reports those errors. E.g:

```
for port in {8079..8081}; do
  if echo >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/$port; then
    echo "port $port is open"
  else
    echo "port $port is closed"
  fi
done 2>/dev/null
```

<sup>*</sup> Or the if block, or whatever beyond the scope of `echo`. Neither the standard nor bash manual makes an explicit remark on why this works, I guess it's just common sense.