# Ignore errors when writing with echo

Tags: bash, echo

I'm using a bash script to set up GPIO pins on a raspberry pi like so:

```
for i in 2 3 9 10 11
do
    echo $i > /sys/class/gpio/export
    sudo chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/gpio$i/*
done
```

This works fine, except if the relevant files have already been made, in which case the echo command returns with an error

```
-bash: echo: write error: Device or resource busy
```

I wanted to supress this error, but it seems all the techniques I know off:

```
echo 2 > /sys/class/gpio/export || true
echo 2 > /sys/class/gpio/export || :
echo 2 > /sys/class/gpio/export >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Do not work in this case. How can I supress error messages coming from this sort of write to file with echo command?

P.S. In my case I can just check if the file exists first, but I'd still like to know how to do this for-the-record.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5185 is your problem / solution

Comment: I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61967697/10248678) a similar question before, it may help.